# Detecting F# record type from C# at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, f#, system.reflection

Is there a way to check if an object is an F# record type at runtime in C# without referencing the FSharp.Core library?

Comment: Why not just reference `FSharp.Core`?

Comment: Because adding a dependency to a library for basically one function is overkill and bloats the dependency tree of another library.

Comment: That's true, but if you already care about recognizing F# records, you might want that dependency anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Record types get marked with `[<CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.RecordType)>]` attribute at compilation. This is what `FSharpType.IsRecord` looks for, you can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/reflect.fs#L738). Discriminated unions get marked in a similar way.

It's possible to reimplement that logic without referring to any `FSharp.Core` types explicitly, i.e. you could look up the attribute by name and have your own copy of `SourceConstructFlags` enum for matching attribute data.

Comment: I basically came to this conclusion.  I was more or less wondering if this was done by someone already.  Thanks!

Comment: Considering how rare it is to consume an F# library without referencing FSharp.Core, I would assume people just use `FSharpType.IsRecord`.

Comment: @Tarmil: That's certainly true, even Newtonsoft.Json (which I assumed did reimplement some of `FSharp.Core` logic to avoid having a dependency) actually does load `FSharp.Core` dynamically to reuse the reflection code, see [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/FSharpUtils.cs).